# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Cross-compiling Raspberry Pi Kernel - modules_install doesn't create files

Tags: kernel

I am trying to build a Raspberry Pi kernel by cross-compiling on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS instance.  The compilation of zImage, modules, and dtbs all complete as expected.

However, when I run the make module_install:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH make modules_install ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=temppath/ext4
```

and then ls in temppath/ext4, the directory is empty.

The same thing happens when I run:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH make dtbs_install ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=temppath/fat32
```

the temppath/fat32 directory is empty.

Both modules_install and dtbs_install provide command line output similar to this:

```
  ...
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-i-sabre-codec.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ics43432.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-pcm1794a.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-pcm186x-i2c.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-pcm186x.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-pcm5102a.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-pcm512x-i2c.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-pcm512x.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-sgtl5000.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-sigmadsp-i2c.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-sigmadsp.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-spdif-rx.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-spdif-tx.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-tas5713.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-tlv320aic32x4-i2c.ko
  INSTALL sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-tlv320aic32x4.ko
  ...
```

However, no files are created.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: This is not a generic linux (*SE's Unix & Linux is that*), or r.pi (*SE's Raspberry pi is that*), but you haven't provided the link with a Ubuntu release or anything to make it on-topic for this site.

Comment: @guiverc, Sorry, I am cross compiling on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS box.  Since I am cross compiling, my assumption is the problem is with Ubuntu 18.04.  I updated the question with the link to the Ubuntu release.